# Backup of SQL Server Developer while being restored yells that it has data compression enabled that is only avaliable on enterprise edition

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-2014

I'm fighting with TFS Server 2015's backups that originally run on **SQL Server 2012 Developer** and I'm trying to restore it on other server -MSSQL 2014 Developer edition

**PS: Generally this process itself is painful and if anybody will have to do that, then do not estimate anything below week for that**

Backups are **scheluded backups by TFS Server 2015**

I'm trying anything to restore those backups - backuping it via TFS Server Console or manually via SQL Management Studio and everything basically ends with that:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='C:\backup\Tfs_Configuration_986.bak'

RESTORE DATABASE MyTempCopy FROM DISK='C:\backup\Tfs_Configuration_986.bak'
```

> Database 'MyTempCopy' cannot be started in this edition of SQL Server because part or all of object 'tbl_CatalogNode' is enabled with data compression or vardecimal storage format. Data compression and vardecimal storage format are only supported on SQL Server Enterprise Edition.
>
> Database 'MyTempCopy' cannot be started because some of the database functionality is not available in the current edition of SQL Server.

Anybody has an idea how is that even possible?

I've seen that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance?view=tfs-2015

Thx in advance

Comment: Off-topic - belongs on [dba]( https://stackoverflow.com/). But you indirectly raise azure yet you say nothing specifically about it nor about the various versions and editions you are using. It is common to make mistakes about which edition you are using since (generally) any version of SSMS or VS can access any version/edition of sql server. So - in which actual version and edition (of your sql server instance) are you running the 2 backup commands you posted? And that filelistonly command should NOT generate that error.

Comment: The error message is telling you the exact problem. What is your question?

Comment: @SMor Im executing those SQLs in the database, where I want to restore backups - 2014 Developer

Comment: @DanielMann I have two developer edition databases, but error says that my backup is using features from enterprise edition and because of it I cannot restore that backup - it's quite weird

Comment: You don't execute "SQLS in the database". The database engine executes them. But run the query "select @@version" in a query window when connected to your target server instance and post the results. You should also execute the restore headeronly command. Add that information to your OP - not as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Developer edition is actually SQL Server Enterprise edition but core and memory capped.  When installing TFS it assumes EE thus it enables compression in the DBs.  Here is an article on turning off compression for TFS.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2712111/disabling-sql-server-data-compression-in-tfs-databases.  You can then take a new backup and you'll be able to restore in standard edition.

Cheers,
ET